# Border Gradient with Border Radius

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients

I have the following CSS:

```
a.btn.white-grad {
    background: $lgrey;
    color: #313149 !important;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570);
    border-image-slice: 20;
    float: left;
    @include font-size(26);
    margin: 75px 0;
}
```

Adding `border-radius: 5px` doesn't seem to do anything. I figured it's because I'm using a border gradient... is there a way for me to achieve the desired 5px border radius at all?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

***2024**: If you **want transparency**, I recommend using the **CSS mask method** since the support is pretty good now*

---

You cannot use `border-radius` with gradient. Here is another idea where you can rely on multiple background and adjust the `background-clip`:

```css
.white-grad {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#ccc 0 0) padding-box, /*this is your grey background*/
    linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570) border-box;
  color: #313149;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 75px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-grad"> Some text here</div>

<div class="white-grad"> Some long long long text here</div>

<div class="white-grad"> Some long long <br>long text here</div>
```

[image: CSS border gradient with radius]

---

### CSS Mask method

Here is a different idea with CSS using `mask` where you will have transparency and it will also be responsive:

```css
.white-grad {
  color: #313149;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 75px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.white-grad:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570);
  -webkit-mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
          mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;

}
```

```html
<div class="white-grad"> Some text here</div>

<div class="white-grad"> Some long long long text here</div>

<div class="white-grad"> Some long long <br>long text here</div>
```

[image: CSS border radius with linear gradient]

With CSS variables, we can make it easy to adjust:

```css
.white-grad {
  --b:5px;  /* border width*/
  --r:15px; /* the radius */

  color: #313149;
  padding: calc(var(--b) + 5px);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 75px 0;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.white-grad:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  padding: var(--b);
  border-radius: var(--r);
  background: var(--c,linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570)); 
  -webkit-mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
          mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-grad"> Some text here</div>

<div class="white-grad" style="--r:20px;--b:10px;--c:linear-gradient(140deg,red,yellow,green)"> Some long long long text here</div>

<div class="white-grad"  style="--r:30px;--b:8px;--c:linear-gradient(-40deg,black 50%,blue 0)"> Some long long <br>long text here</div>

<div class="white-grad"  style="--r:40px;--b:20px;--c:conic-gradient(black,orange,purple)"> Some long long <br>long text here<br> more and more more and more</div>
```

[image: CSS gradient mask with border radius]

Related question to get a different effect: [How do you apply a gradient from outer to inner, only to borders, in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61184968/8620333)

---

The above examples cover also the circle shape:

```css
.white-grad {
  --b:5px;  /* border width*/

  color: #313149;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.white-grad:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  inset: 0;
  background: var(--c,linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570));
  padding: var(--b);
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
          mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-grad"></div>

<div class="white-grad" style="--b:10px;--c:linear-gradient(140deg,red,yellow,green)"></div>

<div class="white-grad"  style="--b:8px;--c:linear-gradient(-40deg,black 50%,blue 0)"></div>

<div class="white-grad"  style="--b:20px;--c:conic-gradient(black,orange,purple)"></div>
```

[image: CSS circular border with gradient]

Related question in case you want to apply an animation to the border: [Button with transparent background and rotating gradient border](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65935742/8620333)

---

Also different radius shapes:

```css
.white-grad {
  --b:5px;  /* border width*/

  color: #313149;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.white-grad:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  background: var(--c,linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570));
  padding: var(--b);
  border-radius: var(--r,50%);
  -webkit-mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
         mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-grad" style="--r:50% 0 50% 50%;"></div>

<div class="white-grad" style="--b:10px;--r:50% 0;--c:linear-gradient(140deg,red,yellow,green)"></div>

<div class="white-grad"  style="--b:8px;--r:50% 0 0;--c:linear-gradient(-40deg,black 50%,blue 0)"></div>

<div class="white-grad"  style="--b:20px;--r:50% 50% 0 0;--c:conic-gradient(black,orange,purple)"></div>
```

[image: CSS curved shape with gradient border]

and different border thickness:

```css
.white-grad {
  --b:5px;  /* border width*/

  color: #313149;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.white-grad:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  background: var(--c,linear-gradient(#9c20aa, #fb3570));
  padding: var(--b);
  border-radius:var(--r,50%);
  -webkit-mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
          mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-grad" style="--b:0 0 20px 20px;--r:50% 0 50% 50%;"></div>

<div class="white-grad" style="--b:10px 0 10px 0;--r:50% 0;--c:linear-gradient(140deg,red,yellow,green)"></div>

<div class="white-grad"  style="--b:8px 0px 0px 8px;--r:50% 0 0;--c:linear-gradient(40deg,black 50%,blue 0)"></div>

<div class="white-grad"  style="--b:20px 20px 0 20px;--r:50% 50% 0 0;--c:conic-gradient(pink,orange,red,pink)"></div>
```

[image: Linear gradient curved shape]

---

### SVG method

You can also consider SVG like below:

```css
svg {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
      <linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
         <stop stop-color="#9c20aa" offset="0"/>
         <stop stop-color="#fb3570" offset="1"/>
      </linearGradient>
   </defs>
  <rect x="5" y="5" height="100%" width="100%" style="width:calc(100% - 10px);height:calc(100% - 10px)" rx="20" ry="20" stroke-width="10" fill="transparent" stroke="url(#Gradient)"/>
</svg>
```

That you can apply as background:

```css
.white-grad {
    background:url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ><defs><linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop stop-color="%239c20aa" offset="0"/><stop stop-color="%23fb3570" offset="1"/></linearGradient></defs><rect x="5" y="5" width="100%" height="100%" style="height:calc(100% - 10px);width:calc(100% - 10px)" rx="20" ry="20" stroke-width="10" fill="transparent" stroke="url(%23Gradient)"/></svg>');
    color: #313149;
    padding:25px;
    border-radius:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 75px 0;
}

body {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-grad"> Some text here</div>

<div class="white-grad"> text very loooooooooooong here</div>
```

And the same way as `mask` where you can get the gradient outside of the SVG:

```css
.white-grad {
  color: #313149;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 75px 0;
  background-size: 0 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.white-grad::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-image: inherit;
  background-size: auto;
  --mask: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ><rect x="5" y="5" width="100%" height="100%" style="height:calc(100% - 10px);width:calc(100% - 10px)" rx="20" ry="20" stroke-width="10" fill="transparent" stroke="white"/></svg>');
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="white-grad" style="background-image:linear-gradient(to right,blue,red)"> Some text here</div>

<div class="white-grad" style="background-image:linear-gradient(black,lightblue,green)"> text very loooooooooooong here</div>

<div class="white-grad" style="background-image:radial-gradient(blue,pink)"> text very<br> loooooooooooong here</div>
```

[image: CSS border gradient with SVG mask]

---

You can also use it as common element and consider `position:absolute` to place it around the text:

```css
.white-grad {
  color: #313149;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 75px 0;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.white-grad > svg {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}

body {
  background: yellow;
}

.hide {
 height:0;
 width:0;
}
```

```html
<svg class="hide" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient id="Gradient" x1="0" x2="100" y1="0" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop stop-color="#9c20aa" offset="0"/><stop stop-color="#fb3570" offset="1"/></linearGradient></defs><rect x="5" y="5" width="100%" height="100%" id="border" style="height:calc(100% - 10px);width:calc(100% - 10px)" rx="20" ry="20" stroke-width="10" fill="transparent" stroke="url(#Gradient)"/></svg>


<div class="white-grad"> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <use href="#border" />
</svg>
Some text here</div>

<div class="white-grad"> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <use href="#border" />
</svg>
text very loooooooooooong here</div>
```

Comment: How to get a transparent background with your solution ? Thanks !

Comment: I love you. 

@NoéVIRICEL if you change the #ccc value in the first linear-gradient to transparent, that should work

Comment: @mikespitz_8 the first one won't work with transparency, you need to consider the other solutions for transparency (the SVG or the mask)

Comment: This is really cool, but it seems that if the box background and page background are different colors, the page background square corner will stick out from behind the border.

Comment: What are the `--b`, `--r`, and `--c` attributes are called? They look like a shorthand but I can't find reference to it anywhere. Thank you for this wonderful answer.

Comment: @Willow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: Got the mask version working on Safari by setting `-wekit-mask-composite` to `source-out` or `xor`

Comment: best answer here. also found a similar reference [article here](https://nikitahl.com/gradient-border-css)

Comment: In the case of "CCS mask method", why do we use "#fff" in the later "mask:" when the gradient is of other colours?

Comment: @MrJWolf the color inside mask doesn't matter, it needs to be a solid color without transparency (you can use #000, red, blue, #f00, etc). The color your see comes from the background definition

Answer (score 7):

## 2023 - single element, no pseudo elements, no SVG, no masks.

I can't take credit for this, I saw this on a website (I forgot the site and can't find it again).

- It's just a normal `button` with rounded edges and a gradient background
- It uses a `box-shadow` that is `inset` to fill the inside with white
- It has a 2px border which is actually transparent, so the very edge of the button shows through

```css
body {
  background: aliceblue;
}

.gradient-border {  
  border-radius: 24px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red 0%, blue 100%);
  /* Fill the inside with white */
  background-origin: border-box;
  box-shadow: inset 0 100vw white;
  /* A transparent border, so the very edge of the button shows through */
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<button class="gradient-border">Hello</button>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that, unlike with the masking method, you cannot have a (semi)transparent background. You could use blending **IF** every pixel of the page background is either darker or lighter than every pixel of the text and border... which may happen, but is rarely the case. The fill with `box-shadow` method also isn't the right choice if the button needs to have a gradient background.

Comment: Thanks @Ana. Yes I agree those are all reasonable criticisms. In our case I didn't need transparent background or gradient fills, so these limits were acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap the button in a div and set the `border-radius` on that parent div. In order to work, you will have to set `overflow:hidden` to that parent div as well. Like so:

```css
.btn-wrap {
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 60px;
}
a.btn.white-grad {
    background: #eee;
    color: #313149 !important;
    border: 20px solid #000;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, #9c20aa, #fb3570);
    border-image-slice: 20;
    line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
 <div class="btn-wrap">
  <a href="#" class="btn white-grad">link</a>
 </div>
```