# CSS rotation create unwanted border around divs

Tags: css, rotation, overflow, border

I was trying to do the pie chart based on three divs. However, there's always some unwanted border around the divs. Also, they'll expand or shrink while zooming in and out.

Try many ways on other similar questions' solutions. Still can't work.

[image]

codepen link https://codepen.io/DavidLee0314/pen/PXWzYJ?editors=1100

```css
* {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.pie {
  left: 40%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 174px;
  height: 174px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.pie .small-box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.pie .grey {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #f3f5f2;
}
.pie .green {
  transform: translateX(25%);
  background-color: #222;
}
.pie .change {
  transform-origin: left center 0;
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1) translateX(50%) rotate(0deg);
  background-color: #f3f5f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="pie">
  <div class="small-box green"></div>
  <div class="small-box grey"></div>
  <div class="small-box change"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably sub-pixel rounding.

Comment: can you use better color to make it more visible?

Comment: @TemanAfif I edited the original post to black color.

Comment: @davidLee do you need this shape exactlly? can I recommand you new code?

Comment: you can have a look at this for another idea : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205399/percent-pie-chart-with-css-only/52205730#52205730 .. it's almost the same, simply remove the top gradient to have a pie

Comment: @ לבני מלכה Yes you can, if there're other workarounds. But I still want to solve this issue.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Cool syntax! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

just use this at *:

> Border: none:

```css
    * {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: none;
    }
    .pie{
        left: 40%;
        top: 30%;
        width: 174px;
        height: 174px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 0;

        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .small-box {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .grey {
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        background-color: #f3f5f2;
    }

    .green {
        transform: translateX(25%);
    }

    .change {
        transform-origin: left center 0;
        transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0) translateX(50%)  rotate(0deg);
        background-color: #f3f5f2;
    }
```

```html
<div class="pie">
    <div class="small-box green"></div>
    <div class="small-box grey"></div>
    <div class="small-box change"></div>
</div>
```