# Filling a circle border by percent

Tags: css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I tried implementing several guides to creating a circle which fills according to a percentage but i can't seem to get it to work (no animation, only a static CSS circle).

The circle border currently abides to `background-image: linear-gradient` which i first set to a `(90+(360*0.percent))deg` and a second one which is set to `90deg`. It works well on the first 50% but beyond that it doesn't fill accordingly.

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.circle-border {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #E53B3B;
  background-image: linear-gradient(162deg, transparent 50%, #f0f0f0 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, #f0f0f0 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-border">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

What values of `linear-gradient` should be changed when i want the circle to be filled for more than 50%?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205730/8620333 almost the same with all the cases

Comment: [This](http://circle.firchow.net/) is nice pure CSS3 solution, with [source code](http://circle.firchow.net/css-circle.zip).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For first linear part, you can use `linear-gradient:(270deg,...)` for filling 50% of the circle.

For other linear part, you can increase the angle **(270°+)** to fill more than 50% of the circle *(360° or 0° = 75% of the circle ... 90° = 100% of the circle)*

For example: `linear-gradient(270deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, black 50%, lightgray 50%)` combination creates a circle with a lightgray background, filled with seventy-five percent black color. *(snippet below)*

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.circle-border {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #E53B3B;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, black 50%, transparent 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, black 50%, lightgray 50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-border">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as needed.

Answer (score -3):

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.circle-border {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #E53B3B;
  background-image: linear-gradient(162deg, transparent 100%, #f0f0f0 100%), linear-gradient(90deg, #f0f0f0 -100%, transparent 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-border">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Just have to play with the numbers.

Comment: with what number exactly?

Comment: Compare OP's CSS with mine.