# css circle mask with variable border width

Tags: css, mask

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve something like the image shown using image masking?
[image: Sample Image]

Blue effect on top left is not required. I want to get the circle masking.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two elements with the same background and adjust the background-size/background-position to create the illusion of this effect:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1057/800/800);
  background-size:auto 220px;
  background-position:top left;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:inherit;
  background-position:bottom left;
  border-radius:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Here is a more generic way using CSS variable to easily control it:

```css
.box {
  --b:-20px; /* Bottom of the pseudo element*/
  --l:10px;  /* Left of the pseudo element*/
  --s:2; /*size of the pseudo element (as a scale factor)*/
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1057/800/800);
  background-size:auto calc(100% - var(--b));
  background-position:top left;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:var(--b);
  left:var(--l);
  width:calc(100%/var(--s));
  height:calc(100%/var(--s));
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:auto calc(100%*var(--s) - var(--b));
  background-position:bottom 0 left calc(-1 * var(--l));
  border-radius:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box" style="--s:3;l:50px;"></div>

<div class="box" style="--s:1.5;l:50px;--b:-10px"></div>
```

And you can easily add borders:

```css
.box {
  --b:-20px; /* Bottom of the pseudo element*/
  --l:10px;  /* Left of the pseudo element*/
  --s:2; /*size of the pseudo element (as a scale factor)*/
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1057/800/800);
  background-size:auto calc(100% - var(--b));
  background-position:top left;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid blue;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:var(--b);
  left:var(--l);
  width:calc(100%/var(--s));
  height:calc(100%/var(--s));
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:auto calc(100%*var(--s) - var(--b));
  background-position:bottom 0 left calc(-1 * var(--l));
  border-radius:inherit;
  border:inherit;
  box-sizing:inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:3;l:50px;">

</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:1.5;l:50px;--b:-10px">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Temani. Can you also guide me with the border thing... Blue one is manageable. What about the white border which only visible on some part of picture

Comment: @booota this will probably help you for the border: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205730/8620333

Comment: once again thanks. I just noticed that this is done by using image as background. Can we do it using an image tag?

Comment: @booota I don't think so as the main trick is to rely on background where I can simulate this using background properties