# Border gradient with radius and transparency

Tags: html, css

I want to do something like this:

[image]

I want a `border-radius`, `transparency` (to see the background), and the possibility to fill from 0% to 100% the `border`.

For the moment, I have this code:

```css
body{
    background: lightgrey;
}

.avatar{
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.avatar:before{
    width: 180px;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    inset: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 25%, blue 25%, blue);
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
    -webkit-mask-composite: clear;
    mask-composite: clear;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="avatar"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How is it possible to fill X% of the border?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an idea based on [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205730/8620333):

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius :50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: conic-gradient(from -136deg, blue calc(var(--p)*.76),#f3f3f3 0);
  -webkit-mask:
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-out;
          mask-composite:exclude;
   clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%, 50% 50%,0 100%);
}

body {
  background:linear-gradient(to right,red,yellow);
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:5%;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:20%;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:50%;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:60%;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:75%;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--p:100%;"></div>
```

Comment: Nice answer! I understand the -136deg, but why the *.76?

Comment: @ValentinS. because you don't have to fill a full circle but less than a full circle so we don't need to go to 100% but rather to 76% only.

Comment: And do you have a solution for Firefox to remove the gradient line at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

This is called a **radial progress bar** is case you want to search for more examples. Here is a small example:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(red var(--progress), gray 0deg);
  font-size: 0;
}

div::after {
  content: attr(data-progress) '%';
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div data-progress="80" style="--progress: 80%;"></div>
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/coolis6/pen/BaVdjgN) is a better solution based on what you asked.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's brilliant, but can you please show how to create only a portion of circle as asked?

Comment: Yes. [here](https://codepen.io/coolis6/pen/BaVdjgN) is what you are looking for. The trick here is that you have to adjust the height and the width according to your needs and the use of JavaScript to rotate the element to see the filled effect for the background.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And if I want to set the height of barOverflow to 70px instead of 45px, I have to add dynamically a border-top-color to fill more than 180°?

Comment: Yes. That is because the bar that is filled is actually a rectangle with border-radius to make it round and border colors for the fill. Now depending on how much you set its height,  its other sides will be visible. So in this case you will have to fill the border-top or border-left according to which side it will be shown. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

try like below,

```css
   body{
        background: lightgrey;
    }
    
    .avatar{
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .avatar:before{
        width: 180px;
        aspect-ratio: 1;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        inset: 0;
        padding: 8px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 25%, blue 25%, blue);
        -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
        mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
        -webkit-mask-composite: clear;
        mask-composite: clear;
    }
    .mainside{
        
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .mainside:before{
        width: 180px;
        aspect-ratio: 1;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9;
        inset: 0;
        padding: 8px;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 90%, #878789 25%, #adadad);
        -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
        mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
        -webkit-mask-composite: clear;
        mask-composite: clear;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="mainside">
                <div class="avatar"></div>
            </div>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```