# How to make semi donut from donut chart on svg&css?

Tags: html, css, svg, charts, donut-chart

I have donut which is made in svg. I want to upgrade it to semi donut somehow.

```css
.donut-ring {
    stroke: #EBEBEB;
}

.donut-segment-2 {
    stroke: green;
    animation: donut 1s;
}

@keyframes donut {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 0, 100;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 25, 75;
    }
}
```

```html
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 40" class="donut">
    <circle class="donut-hole" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-ring" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke-width="3.5"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment donut-segment-2" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke-width="3.5" stroke-dasharray="25 75" stroke-dashoffset="50"></circle>
  </svg>
```

Title (50%) is not essential, it is for clarity.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52205730/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's not a semi donut

Answer (score 0):

Just clip away what you don't want to see.

```css
.donut-ring {
    stroke: #EBEBEB;
}

.donut-segment-2 {
    stroke: green;
    animation: donut 1s;
}

@keyframes donut {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 0, 100;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 25, 75;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 40" class="donut">
    <defs>
       <clipPath id="c">
         <rect width="40" height="20"/>
       </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <g clip-path="url(#c)">
    <circle class="donut-hole" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-ring" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke-width="3.5"></circle>
    <circle class="donut-segment donut-segment-2" cx="20" cy="20" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke-width="3.5" stroke-dasharray="25 75" stroke-dashoffset="50"></circle>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Comment: I need to set percent of green part. stroke-dasharray="25 75" means that green part will be 25% out of 100. If I just cut my svg It won't calculate percent of green area correctly

Comment: adjust the stroke-dasharray values. or change the pathLength

Comment: Could I ask you to provide an example with adjusted pathLength?

Comment: pathLength="X" where X is a number - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small Web Component to do Pie Charts: https://pie-meister.github.io/

With some extra CSS everyone who can do HTML can create a chart:

```html
<script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister.min.js"></script>

<pie-chart stroke-width="200" pull="-200">
    <style>
      svg {
        background:pink;
        transform:rotate(-90deg);
      }
      [hide], text {
        display:none
      }
    </style>
    <slice size="20"></slice>
    <slice size="30"></slice>
    <slice hide size="50"></slice>
 </pie-chart>
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't need extra lib