# Resize svg in div keeping rounded corners aspect

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a .svg displayed within a `<div>` containing text, the div size changes and its border adapt with it. The svg border have rounded corners and I need to keep them after resize.

I used `preserveAspectRatio="none"` but the corners are deformed.

html

```
<div class="border">
 <p>text.</p>
 <%- include('../../public/img/border.svg'); -%>
</div>
```

**.css**

```
.border svg {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**.svg**

```
<svg id="level1" data-name="Livello 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 31.27 31.27">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cs-1 {
        fill: none;
        stroke-miterlimit: 10;
        stroke-width: 5px;
        stroke: url("#Gradiente_7");
      }
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient_7" x1="25.25" y1="32.29" x2="6.02" y2="-1.02" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0.1"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/></linearGradient>
  </defs><rect class="border-unique-ability" x="1" y="1" width="29.27" height="29.27" rx="4.8"  vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" preserveAspectRatio="none"/></svg>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why didnt you use "border-radius" property?

Comment: @Dev on SVG? how?

Comment: He probably wants to keep the gradient, in which case I'd suggest going a route [like this](https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/) instead.

Comment: @Artemis not on the svg, on the div instead

Comment: You won't make it by an svg image. See this article
https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/
and use two divs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496204/border-gradient-with-border-radius/51496341#51496341 this post worked for me. Not svg but fits the purpose. Otherwise using rx in css might help since according to specs you can set the rx with css these days...