# Div with radius, transparent background, and gradient border

Tags: html, css, gradient

i trying to create div like this picture:

[image]

background - transparent
radius - 8px
gradient color for border

and i trying to do this with this code:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.avatar {
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    border: transparent solid 8px;
    background: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) padding-box,
    linear-gradient(to right, #11bbfe, #8c41fb) border-box;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar"></div>
```

but with this code the background are #fff and not transparent,
if i will change

```
linear-gradient(#fff 0 0)
```

to

```
linear-gradient(transparent 0 0)
```

the background will be the gradient and not transparent

how can i do that?
tnx

Comment: Please post it with runnable code in fiddle or stackoverflow code editor

Comment: @SanthoshKumar ok i changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51496341/17473197

Answer (score 2):

changed background color to gradient, so you can see the tranparity.
With the padding, you can change the thiccness of the border.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, white, black);
}

.avatar {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.avatar:before {
  width: 180px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #11bbfe, #8c41fb);
  -webkit-mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
          mask: 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`-webkit-mask`](https://webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/) to add a border overlay for the circle

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.avatar {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  position: relative;
}

.avatar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #11bbfe, #8c41fb);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar"></div>
```

Comment: Why would you need the prefixed version of mask for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature does not fully support all browsers, `webkit` is to help browsers recognize it as Webkit's styles (not all browsers' styles) @cloned