# Use text as a clipping mask over an image during hover

Tags: html, css, image, clipping, background-clip

I'm trying to create a hover effect for an image whereby:

1. A headline text is revealed
2. This headline text acts a clipping mask over the image

in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdUUN.jpg), state 1 (no hover) is on the left. you *just* see the image. state 2 (hover) is on the right. text would appear as a clipping mask for the image, so you only see the image through the text when hovered.

This text would be a hyperlink to a different page

I've tried using css `background-clip` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72722112/combining-two-different-background-clips-in-hover-state) to make this work, but I couldn't get it so that the first state was just the image, no text outline.

Can anyone help?

I'd really love a whole grid of these images, acting as thumbnails for different blog posts!

thank you!

Comment: Please show the relevant code. I especially didn’t understand how there was a text outline (as opposed to text). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Each item in the gallery can have a background image which covers the item and then on hover the background is clipped to the text.

This snippet has the gallery as a CSS grid with square items, but of course alter this to whatever layout you require.

This snippet gives this sort of effect:

[image]

```css
.gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: 100vw;
}

.gallery>* {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  background-image: var(--image);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.gallery>*:hover {
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}

.gallery>*:nth-child(1) {
  --image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1015/1024/1024");
}

.gallery>*:nth-child(2) {
  --image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1024/1024");
}

.gallery>*:nth-child(3) {
  --image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1024/1024");
}

.gallery>*:nth-child(4) {
  --image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1019/1024/1024");
}

.gallery>*:nth-child(5) {
  --image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1020/1024/1024");
}

.gallery>*:nth-child(6) {
  --image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/1021/1024/1024");
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="#">1st<br>IMAGE</a>
  <a href="#">2nd<br>IMAGE</a>
  <a href="#">3rd<br>IMAGE</a>
  <a href="#">4th<br>IMAGE</a>
  <a href="#">5th<br>IMAGE</a>
  <a href="#">6th<br>IMAGE</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

It was necessary to have a parent div with the same background, and hide it on hovering.

```css
      .container {
        width: fit-content;
        background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/20316373/pexels-photo-20316373/free-photo-of-antigo-antepassados-anciao-arqueologia.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1")
          no-repeat;
      }
      .container:hover {
        background: none;
      }

      a {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 750px;
        width: 300px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        font-size: 100px;
        position: relative;
        border: none;
        background: var(--i, transparent);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      }

      a:hover {
        --i: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/20316373/pexels-photo-20316373/free-photo-of-antigo-antepassados-anciao-arqueologia.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1");
      }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com"> NOW SOME TEXT </a>
    </div>
```